# Hide specific product attribute terms on WooCommerce variation product dropdown without disable it

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, taxonomy-terms, product-variations

I would like to hide attributes terms or values from variation dropdown list and also enabled not disabled. just hide it from selecting in variations dropdown list because I want To use this variation ID as a single product.

My Example is
[hide attribute value woocommerce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKrwq.png)

I found the below code which helps me of what Exactly I need but it makes the attribute value or variation Id disabled and I can't use it anymore as a single product by variation Id

[Hide specific product attribute terms on WooCommerce variable product dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61598810/hide-specific-product-attribute-terms-on-woocommerce-variable-product-dropdown)

Answer (score 1):

If you can hide an option/attribute only in this dropdown then you should have 2 options:

1. Hide by using CSS
2. Hide by using JS like this-

   option1)

   ```
   $('#test').find('option[text="Domains Num"]').css('display','none'); OR $('#test').find('option[text="Domains Num"]').hide();
   ```

   option2)

   ```
   $('#mySelect option:contains(' + value + ')').css('display','none');
   ```

In your Js file or footer.php page

Comment: Option 1 not working and Option 2, Do I replace value with Domains num to be like that $('#mySelect option:contains(' + Domains Num + ')').css('display','none');