# Hide specific product attribute dropdown on WooCommerce variable products

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

On WooCommerce I have added a 'Brand' product attribute that I use for the variations of some variable products.

This field is displayed on the website product page which isn't really necessary as I can set a default value for the brand. Does anyone know a way to hide this by amending one of the .PHP files. The functions.php for example?

[image: Brand Variable Field]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Important:** A default value (term) need to be set for the product attribute you want to hide in all variations for the related variable products.

You can use the following hooked function that will check if "Brand" attribute is set on your variable product.

The code will hide the first attribute dropdown from this variable product, using an injected inline CSS style rule *(so it's important that "brand" dropdown is the first one above the others)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hide_brands_attribute_dropdown', 1 );
function hide_brands_attribute_dropdown() {
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('variable') && $product->get_attribute('Brand') ){
        ?>
        <style>
        table.variations tbody tr:first-of-type {display:none;}
        </style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related:

- [Hide specific product attribute terms on WooCommerce variable product dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61598810/hide-specific-product-attribute-terms-on-woocommerce-variable-product-dropdown/61599972#61599972)
- [Hide a variation attribute value in Woocommerce variable product dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54985902/hide-a-variation-attribute-value-in-woocommerce-variable-product-dropdown/54987217#54987217)

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response here which I will utilise in due course. I was, however trying to work out if it was possible to hide the entire 'Brand' field from the product page rather than specific attributes from the drop down?