# Hide product attribute on all pages and popups quick overviews

Tags: woocommerce, attributes, hide

I am looking for a way to hide certain product-attributes on all pages, not only the product page. This is because I am working with elementor and buidling my own product templates.

I am using: [Hide specific product attribute dropdown on WooCommerce variable products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62711121/hide-specific-product-attribute-dropdown-on-woocommerce-variable-products/62714386#62714386) answer code, where I replaced for my usage:

```
$product->get_attribute('Brand')
```

with:

```
$product->get_attribute('alt_omschrijving')
```

This works fine for the product-pages but the attribute is still visible on the Quick Overview and in my custom designed product template. Any idea to alter the code so the attribute is hidden for all elements on my site?

Comment: Note that in woocommerce by default there is no "Quick overview" for products… This feature has been added by your theme customization or a plugin.

Comment: tnx .. but is there a way to hide an attribute by default for all occassions? (if the standard value is set).